# how to check null or empty value in mvc view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, view, isnullorempty

I want to check null or empty in view page. i gave code. but it is showing the error. i don't know how to give?

**my code is**

```
 <% foreach (Models.JobPreferredIndustry jpi in Model.JobPreferredIndustries)
 { %>
    <% if (jpi != null) { %>
        <%:jpi.Industry.Name %>
    <%} %>

    <%if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jpi))
    { %>
                        ----------------
    <%} %>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late... Is the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`? Maybe the problem is that your `Model` or `Model.JobPreferredIndustries` is null.

You can add check for null before the `foreach` statement:

```
if(Model != null)
{
  ...
```

or

```
if(Model.JobPreferredIndustries != null)
{
  ...
```